# How to inject custom HttpMessageConveter to Spring WebFlux tests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, spring-test

I have a csv download endpoint that returns `Mono<Pojo>` and produces `text/csv`. I implemented `CsvMessageConveter`, added to `WebMvcConfigurer` and it works fine when I starts the application. However, that bean isn't injected to `WebFluxTest` context and I got `406` unsupported media type when trying to test with `WebTestClient`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please add more info. Code examples for example (snippets).